# What does SS stand for in a React Component declaration?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I don't see anything in the docs specifically about `SS`, I know `P`=props, and `S`=state but `SS`?

**edit**

Sorry, I was referencing this from a React+TypeScript project, namely `@types/react`.  I have added the `typescript` tag.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L395

Comment: Can you please provide a link of docs where you read this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's used in the [return value of `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L611) so I'm betting it stands for **S**nap**S**hot.

> Runs before React applies the result of `render` to the document, and
>   returns an object to be given to componentDidUpdate. Useful for saving
>   things such as scroll position before `render` causes changes to it.

And the docs in that file for `componentDidUpdate` show it accepts a third argument called snapshot that says:

> The snapshot is only present if getSnapshotBeforeUpdate is present and returns non-null.

So, `SS` is the user defined type of the snapshot returned by your custom implementation of `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`, which gets passed to `componentDidUpdate` so you can preserve some application specific details from the last render.